# Creating ISO 19115 metadata from REST services

Tags: metadata, rest, iso-19115

I need to create ISO 19115 metadata from REST services on a webpage.  I'm not even sure how to begin on this.  Has anyone here done this or similar tasks before?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/metadata/create-iso-19115-and-iso-19139-metadata.htm

Comment: what sort of REST service?

Answer (score 0):

REST requires hypermedia (HATEOAS), so a good place to start would be a service that provides a hypermedia for ISO 19115 metadata, such as ISO 19139 XML, something based on an OGC CSW service perhaps that supplies a hypermedia for describing the service.  OGC CSW service requests are stateless too, another REST requirement.